# All jupyter contrib nbextensions are marked as possibly incompatible

Tags: jupyter-notebook, incompatibility, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have just installed `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` by:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

When I open a jupyter notebook and navigate to ***Edit -> nbextensions config***, I see the below screen:

[image: nbextensions config]

All extensions are marked as "***possibly incompatible***". A solution is to uncheck the option: "***disable configuration for nbextensions without explicit compatibility***". But is it safe? Any ideas why the `nbextensions` are incombatible?

My package versions are:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
notebook==6.0.1
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.1
```

Comment: If you need to [uninstall these extensions from Jupyter](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html) once you have confirmed none is yet usable safely according to the developers, end of 2020: `jupyter contrib nbextension uninstall --user` (or `--system` if you installed them this way). Then remove the package with pip or conda, e.g. `conda remove jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` (and then wait for slooo...w conda execution)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As you will notice, in **version 0.5.1** of `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` most of the nbextensions are compatible with versions *4.X and 5.X*. For example look at this extension:

[image: nbextension details example]

It you uncheck the option "***disable configuration for nbextensions without explicit compatibility***", you will most probably have no problem using any extension. I guess that the developers haven't yet tested the `jupyter_contrib_extensions` against the new `notebook` *version 6.X* which was recently launched. If you want to have a stable and tested environment, you can *roll back to a previous jupyter notebook version*. The most recent compatible one is **5.7.8**. Just uninstall current `notebook` and install that specific version by executing:

```
pip uninstall notebook
pip install notebook==5.7.8
```

Comment: As of end of 2020 this answer still holds true.

Comment: end of 2021 and this still holds true.

Comment: mid 2022 and this still holds true.

Comment: end of 2022 and this still holds true.

Comment: mid 2023 and this still holds true.